# Filter Array of Objects by NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have an array of objects and I need sort by NSPredicate by a date (the date it's a property of my object)

This is my object:

```
@interface Object:NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *date;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *open;

@end

@implementation Object
- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
     self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-mm-yyyy"];
        self.date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[dictionary objectForKey:@"date"]];
        self.open = [dictionary objectForKey:@"open"];
    }
return self;
}
@end
```

I have an Array ob object like

```
NSArray <Object *> *allData
```

I need to filter the data into allData by the date. But when I try to create NSPredicate like

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)", firstDate, lastDate];
NSArray <Stock *> *result = [self.allData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

I get an error.
I'm not sure if possible to create a predicate by date.

This is the example to data to save into Object.

```
[
{
    "date": "5-Februrary-2020",
    "open": 52.09
},
{
    "date": "6-January-2020",
    "open": 5424
},
...
```

]

The date I convert to NSdate.

I expect a sub-range between the start and end date.

Comment: It would be helpful if you include the error in your question. Also can you share some input and expected output data?

Comment: replace >= with > and try not to change the NSArrays generic object type.

Comment: You don't want a sort, you want a `filter`, that's different. What error do you have? Also, did you even check that your parsing is correct? Because `self.date` seems not correct at all. Just looking at the date format... See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns for reference. Once you fixed that, we might advance on your issue. => Issue is about Date Parsing, not Filtering.